# Writing nested list values to CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have class with nested list properties, I am trying to write the value to CSV file, but I am getting output appended with [{  }] like shown below:

```
Client  TDeals
ABC     [{DealName:59045599,TShape:[{StartDate:"2014-01-
        28T23:00:00",EndDate:"2014-01-28T23:30:00",Volume:0.00},
        {StartDateTime:"2014-01-                
        28T23:30:00",EndDateTime:"2014-01-29T00:00:00",Volume:0.00}}]
```

I want my output in CSV file like shown below:

```
Client      DealNo        StartDate        EndDate         Volume
ABC        59045599         -                -               -
```

Class Properties

```
  public class TRoot
    {
            public string Client { get; set; }
            public List<TDeal> Deals { get; set; }
    }

  public class TDeal
  {
    public string DealName{get;set;}
    public List<TInterval> TShape { get; set; }
  }

  public class TInterval
  {
     public string StartDate{ get; set; }
     public string EndDate{ get; set; }
     public string Volume {get;set;}
  }
```

I am using ServiceStack.Text to create CSV file from object

```
ServiceStack.Text.CsvSerializer.SerializeToWriter<TRoot>(TRoot, writer);
```

Reference URL
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text

Comment: If you want like "shown below", then write your custom code, or if the library, which you've used, not working - contact the developer/support of that library. But if you look closely to output example given in ServiceStack's github page, it is wrapped in `[{}]`.

Comment: @SeM is their any other library which will help in writing nested list to csv file

Comment: sorry, but I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new class for single csv line:

```
public class CsvLine
{
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string DealName { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Volume { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can transfrom your objects into collection of lines with Linq `SelectMany` method:

```
TRoot root = ...
var lines = root.Deals.SelectMany(d => d.TShape.Select(s => new CsvLine
{
    Client = root.Client,
    DealName = d.DealName,
    StartDate = s.StartDate,
    EndDate = s.EndDate,
    Volume = s.Volume
})).ToArray();
```

Then call `SerializeToWriter` on that collection

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to "flatten" your output to CSV.

Create one more class that will be a mirror of what you would like to have in CSV file. Before writing to the file, convert your `TRoot` to that new class and write it to CSV.

Quite quick and elegant solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) to create the CSV file. First you will have to flatten out root object using Linq and pass them to CSV writer to create file.

Sample below show how to

```
private static void Test()
{
    TRoot root = new TRoot() { Client = "ABC", Deals = new List<TDeal>() };
    root.Deals.Add(new TDeal
    {
        DealName = "59045599",
        TShape = new List<TInterval>()
    {
        new TInterval { StartDate = DateTime.Today.ToString(), EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2).ToString(), Volume = "100" },
        new TInterval { StartDate = DateTime.Today.ToString(), EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2).ToString(), Volume = "200" }
    }
    });

    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter("nestedObjects.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
    {
        w.Write(root.Deals.SelectMany(d => d.TShape.Select(s => new { ClientName = root.Client, DealNo = d.DealName, StartDate = s.StartDate, EndDate = s.EndDate, Volume = s.Volume })));
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
ClientName,DealNo,StartDate,EndDate,Volume
ABC,59045599,1/17/2018 12:00:00 AM,1/19/2018 12:00:00 AM,100
ABC,59045599,1/17/2018 12:00:00 AM,1/19/2018 12:00:00 AM,200
```

For more information about it, visit the codeproject article at

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1155891/Cinchoo-ETL-CSVWriter

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.