# Output Entites to csv

Tags: c#, csv

I am currently working on a business project. Since my application I have to generate data. So I get a core entity that contains other entites as well as lists etc.

All of its data must be sent to a partner API that requires sending in CSV format.

My question is, what is the best solution for applying conversion?

Comment: There are a lot of duplicate questions *and* libraries that can do this easily. Did you try something? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is a library that springs to mind

Comment: the problem I encounter is that I work with nested entities. it is therefore difficult to have a clear vision to match the CSV format. so I know that there are several solutions but precisely which one can best fit this case

Comment: csvHelper seems too rigid, I'll take a look at the advanced features

Comment: @CamilleColvray there is no such thing as a nested entity in CSV. It's supposed to be a *simple, flat* format. If you think CsvHelper is rigid, you are doing it wrong. Consumers of your file won't be able to do anything with it.

Comment: @CamilleColvray if you want nested entities, you want XML or JSON, not CSV.

Comment: @CamilleColvray perhaps you should look to AutoMapper to flatten your objects first, then export them to a CSV

Comment: actually the csv format is imposed by our partners. Working in two stages seemed more right. First step development OOP, and secondly conversion to CSV. CSVHelper could help me if I converted in stages, so by object one by one. I'll see more closely

Comment: @CamilleColvray for nested entities take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48299237/4685428) answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
 public static string ObjectToCsvData(object obj)
 {
     if (obj == null)
     {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("obj", "Value can not be null or Nothing!");
     }

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     Type t = obj.GetType();
     PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();

     for (int index = 0; index < pi.Length; index++)
     {
         sb.Append(pi[index].GetValue(obj, null));

         if (index < pi.Length - 1)
         {
            sb.Append(",");
         }
     }

     return sb.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Not my downvote but CSV doesn't mean put a single object's properties in a string with commas

Comment: You mean you have nested objects?

Comment: thanks i'll test that code, but actually, I do not think that GetProperties () can handle the nesting of entities

Comment: @CamilleColvray CSV files don't have nested entities. They don't have *entities*. They are simple values separated by a delimiter. Anything between the delimiters is text

Comment: Yeah you can't use nested entities in CSV files since we can't specify the name of properties; its only value.